# What is that word?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

You know, that word that's on the tip of your tongue. It's that elusive word that escapes the brain but you know it's there. I can't exactly place it. But if you mention it, I'll recognize it immediately.

I tried searching the web for it but I don't know the search terms for that word.

I'd find a use for it to describe in the following sentence:

> I was going to say *foo*, but it doesn't fit. What is the ________ that should fit in the blank?

Comment: You refer to a nebuloevaporant. It's referenced on that obscure yet reliably authoritative linguistic tool at...oh what is it. Something .com. O.O

Comment: Word?  I almost feel like this should be on Puzzling.SE!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware of the single vote power. I'll reopen if you explain why it is not a duplicate. But it is also not clear what you are asking. Check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

Comment: @SrJoven: Ah, sorry to be the killjoy then :) But at least I secured your question and it won't be closed.

Comment: Also, meta because this is the way questions are asked on this site. :) No, not that question. No, not that word.

Comment: The quick answer...'aphasia'. Wait, that's the description of the _problem_. Are you looking for the word itself that is forgotten/on the tip of your tongue?

Comment: @Mitch No, not the problem, I'm looking for a word for missing word.

Comment: @ermanen I think I might reopen as the duplicate isn't a duplicate. I'm looking for a word for missing word.

Comment: 'lexical gap' is the word for a missing word...from the lexicon (specifically where parallelism creates a slot that is just not in the lexicon, eg there are gendered terms nephew and niece, but none for cousin). The word for 'word that you can't think of' ... haha well you can't think of it can you! I know, not the particular word but the term to describe any word you can't think of at the moment. I have a feeling there is no such word.

Comment: @Mitch I really was hoping for some creativity in responses. Unfortunately the blue boxes are going to dissuade the obvious *answer*.

Comment: Don't be hung up on getting a single word; 'missing word' or 'word that I can't think of' or 'word at the tip of my tongue' each capture it very well already. Also those are more easily translated.